# Struct Node return address

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a Struct assignment and I am struggling with the return address of my modified struct,
The address is correct yet when I try to access the first value I get 'x' every time as char and -8 or 120 as int (both are 'x' on ascii).
The program takes two number inputs from user and places numbers as chars in a struct node, then sumIs adds number by number in to new struct.
Don't mind the no proper frees the code is not complete, prints are for values checking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    char num;
    struct node* next;
}Node;

Node* sumIs(Node* first,Node* second,int counter1,int counter2)
{
    int rem=0; /*reminder from sum of two numbers*/
    int chSum=0;
    int k=((counter1<counter2)?counter1:counter2);
    Node* new_node;
    new_node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node* head=new_node;
    printf("The address of the head node is %p\n",head);
    printf("The address of the new node is %p\n",new_node);
    if(new_node==NULL)
    {
        free(new_node);
        exit(1);
    }
    for(;k>0;k--)
    {
        Node* new_node;
        new_node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if(new_node==NULL)
        {
            free(new_node);
            exit(1);
        }
        chSum=(first->num-'0')+(second->num-'0')+rem;
        printf("first num is %d %c\nSecond num is %d %c\nchSum is %d\n",first->num,first->num,second->num,second->num,chSum);
        if (chSum>9)
        {
            chSum-=10;
            rem=1;
        }
        new_node->num=chSum;
        printf("new node num is %d\nrem is%d\n",new_node->num,rem);
        first=first->next;
        second=second->next;
    }
    return head;
}

void addChar(Node** head, int* counter)
{
    char endCheck;
    do
    {
        scanf("%c",&endCheck);
        if (endCheck!='\n')
        {
            Node* new_node;
            new_node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
            if(new_node==NULL)
            {
                free(new_node);
                exit(1);
            }
            if (counter==0)
            {
                new_node->next=NULL;
                new_node->next=*head;
                *head=new_node;
                continue;
            }

            new_node->num=endCheck;
            new_node->next=*head;
            *head=new_node;
            *counter+=1;
        }
    }while (endCheck!='\n');
    return;
}


int main()
{
    Node* first;
    Node* second;
    Node* sum;
    Node* dedSum;
    int counter1=0;
    int counter2=0;
    printf("Please enter the first number\n");
    addChar(&first,&counter1);
    printf("Please enter the second number\n");
    addChar(&second,&counter2);
    sum=sumIs(first,second,counter1,counter2);
    printf("sum is %d\n",sum->num);
    printf("The address of the sum node is %p\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

```
 output:
Please enter the first number
123
Please enter the second number
123
The address of the head node is 00020db8
The address of the new node is 00020db8
first num is 51 3
Second num is 51 3
chSum is 6
new node num is 6
rem is0
first num is 50 2
Second num is 50 2
chSum is 4
new node num is 4
rem is0
first num is 49 1
Second num is 49 1
chSum is 2
new node num is 2
rem is0
sum is 120
The address of the sum node is 00020db8

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.268 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: One error: `if (counter==0)` should be `if (*counter==0)`

Comment: 1) free() followed by exit() is silly.  2) "return" as a the last line of your "void" function is silly.  3) Q: Is your question about the return value of "sumIs()"?  Q: do you realize you're [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) "new_node" by declaring it again inside your "for(;k>0;k--)" loop?

Comment: kaylum fixed thank you.
@FoggyDay there are a couple of things that are not finished and as i modified the functions i forgot to remove the return, ty for the silly answer. i will check the shadowing now.

Comment: It looks like you may be assuming that the `char` '1' has value 1 (and likewise for the other digits), but this very unlikely to be true in your C implementation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger but my print %d has the current value...? oh, i think i forgot to adjust the int value back as char...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new_node` variable in the `for` loop, hides the `new_node` at functions scope in `sumIs`.  `head` in `sumIs` is an alias for the the `new_node` that is defined at function scope and then returned by that function. At no point is any work that is done in the `for` loop, being transferred to `head`, so you are essentially returning noise from the heap.

I think you're leaking memory as well.

This is untested, but should get you further along:

```
#include <cstdint>

#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    char num;
    struct node* next;
}Node;

Node* sumIs(Node* first,Node* second,int counter1,int counter2)
{
    int rem=0; /*reminder from sum of two numbers*/
    int chSum=0;
    int k=((counter1<counter2)?counter1:counter2);
    Node *result = NULL;
    Node *current = NULL;
    while(k--)
    {
        if (current == NULL)
        {
            current = result = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
            if (result == NULL) return NULL;
        }
        chSum=(first->num-'0')+(second->num-'0')+rem;
        printf("first num is %d %c\nSecond num is %d %c\nchSum is %d\n",first->num,first->num,second->num,second->num,chSum);
        if (chSum>9)
        {
            chSum-=10;
            rem=1;
        }
        current->num=chSum;
        printf("new node num is %d\nrem is%d\n",current->num,rem);
        first=first->next;
        second=second->next;
        current = current->next = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
    }
    return result;
}

void addChar(Node** head, int* counter)
{
    char endCheck;
    do
    {
        scanf("%c",&endCheck);
        if (endCheck!='\n')
        {
            Node* new_node;
            new_node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
            if(new_node==NULL)
            {
                free(new_node);
                exit(1);
            }
            if (counter==0)
            {
                new_node->next=NULL;
                new_node->next=*head;
                *head=new_node;
                continue;
            }

            new_node->num=endCheck;
            new_node->next=*head;
            *head=new_node;
            *counter+=1;
        }
    }while (endCheck!='\n');
    return;
}


int main()
{
    Node* first;
    Node* second;
    Node* sum;
    Node* dedSum;
    int counter1=0;
    int counter2=0;
    printf("Please enter the first number\n");
    addChar(&first,&counter1);
    printf("Please enter the second number\n");
    addChar(&second,&counter2);
    sum=sumIs(first,second,counter1,counter2);
    printf("sum is %d\n",sum->num);
    printf("The address of the sum node is %p\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

There's an old programmers joke that goes something like

> There's three things that are hard to get right in C programming: naming things and avoiding off by one errors.

Chose your names carefully. Avoid generic names like `Node` or naming variable after their type. The use of current and result are obvious choices in the above code and help you to think about what it is you are operating on, when you are writing your code. Naming things really is hard, especially when you are inexperienced, but it's critical that you develop the skill, or you and those who have to review your code, will likely get confused.

Comment: thank you for the answer i'm modifying it right now.

Comment: Hang-on. You still have a chicken or egg problem...

Comment: @models4fun, there you go, that should get a lot closer to your goal.

Comment: Thank you so much for the elaborated answer! I will try that now, have an amazing day :)

Comment: @models4fun, if you are happy with it, please mark it as the answer this question. If you encounter other problems with the code, start a new question.

Comment: Yes it did solve my problem im going over it right now. thank you again, I was so frustrated lol.